# Input field resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, field

I'm having trouble with re-sizing my search input bar. I've managed to make it re-size when the browser window gets smaller using `width:100%;`. But I can't get the starting width to be 300px without making it always 300px and then it's goes out of the parent div on resize. For some reason it's 185px;

[Here's the jsfiddle of my set-up.](http://jsfiddle.net/u4d9skxp/3/)

Comment: have you tried `min-width` and `max-width`

Comment: Please strip down your fiddle to the absolute minimum of code required to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @lex82 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u4d9skxp/6/)

Comment: You can give min-width to outer div along with scroll bar using overflow-x property.That may solve your problem

Comment: @amol sorry that did nothing. I did try `width:300px` and `overflow:hidden`, and that works, but it's really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are embeding your `input` into a `span` by calling `$('.search2').typeahead`. This `span` has the css-class `twitter-typeahead` wich is not set to `width: 100%;`

Add this to your CSS:

```css
.twitter-typeahead {width: 100%;}
```

Then you need to change your div container css to this (`width: 100%; max-width: 300px;`):

```css
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Leaving `width: 100%;` on your `input` is fine!

See the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/utg4mh6z/1/

Comment: If I remove the `local:data` the search bar doesn't work anymore, since it get's it's data from above `var data`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the `float: left;` and it works. It seems they are not required anyway. At least you don't state it anywhere and floating for 100% width elements makes no sense from my point of view.